# How to Update Progress Bar using Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

How to update progress bar using Background thread in android? It would also change the progress in progress bar. Please help.

AndroidVogue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done similar task using `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` has method `onProgressUpdate(Integer)` that you can call each iteration for example or each time a progress is done during `doInBackground()` by calling `publishProgress()`.

Refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread t=new Thread()
{
public void run()
{
while(some condition)
{
sleep(1000);
Message myMessage = new Message();
myMessage.obj = "success";
handler.sendMessage(myMessage);
}
}
};


private Handler handler=new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            String result=(String)msg.obj;
                     if(result.equals("success")
                     {
                     //update progress bar here
                      }

                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  // this is demonstrate how to update progress bar from a thread 
  private ProgressBar pgb;  //  is a progressBar named with pgb 
  private int progressBarStatus = 0;// is a variable named progressBarStatus and initialize by 0
  // in  onCreate  method find the ui component view horizontal prograssbar named progressBar2  


 public void load_bar(View view) // is a button OnClick
// and i am using a thread with for loop to demonstrate a task and variable progressBarStatus  as status 

  pgb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2) ;// find view by id 

  pgb.setMax(100); // at this point we the maximum value of a progress bar to make it full like we make 100 pices of it 

  pgb.setProgress(0); // initialize the progress bar with 0 % progress

    // progress bar handler that update the status of progress bar . without handler we cant update progress bar from thread 

   progressBarbHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pgb.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use handler, this handler will update the progress bar
you have to do is:
1)send message to handler from you thread
2)update progress bar in handler

Comment: Any idea about how to update progress bar while downloading JSON object from web. it takes hardly 20 seconds. Time is not fixed. It would be less. So how to increment progress in progressbar?

Comment: @AndroidVogue : can you provide sample of your code ? so that I can help you

Comment: one more thing that you can do in your thread is use `yourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){ public void run(){ /* update your progress bar here */ }})`

Answer (score 1):

```
private ProgressBar pgb;
private TextView textview;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;
private Handler progressBarbHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
    pgb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2) ;
}

public void load_bar(View view)
{
    pgb.setMax(100);
    pgb.setProgress(0);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (progressBarStatus = 0; progressBarStatus <= 100; progressBarStatus++) {

                progressBarbHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pgb.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                    }
                });


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Thread you can do it like this just call the function in oncreate method

```
public void loadProgressbar()
{
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (progress = 0; progress <= 100; progress++) {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    }
                });


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```